# AttributeError: module 'redis' has no attribute 'Redis'

Tags: python, caching, docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

### Problem

Installed `redis` module and I cannot establish the client according documentation.
This is a Redis client in a Redis cluster hosted on Docker container.

Following [documentation](https://github.com/redis/redis-py), as you can see:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r.set('foo', 'bar')
True
>>> r.get('foo')
b'bar'
```

#### Error

```
backend-web-1        |     from redis.conversation_memory import redis_client, initiate_user_memory
backend-web-1        |   File "/app/redis/conversation_memory.py", line 5, in <module>
backend-web-1        |     redis_client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
backend-web-1        |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
backend-web-1        | AttributeError: module 'redis' has no attribute 'Redis'
```

**Question**

What's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: That's because you have your own `redis` module at `/app/redis/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a rookie move.

**Never name a folder after an official Python module**

I wrongly named it after my `redis` module, which I am inherently using.

**Lesson**

Name your folder uniquely, if they are to be used as modules.